# OpenXML - embedding objects in Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, embedding

I am trying to embed object into .xlsx document and copy sheets with embedded objects.

**1. Copying sheets**

This looks like straight forward issue. I have created method to copy the sheets:

```
        static void CopySheetInsideWorkbook(string filename, string sheetName, string clonedSheetName)
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart sourceSheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadsheetDocument, sheetName);

            SpreadsheetDocument tempSheet =
                SpreadsheetDocument.Create(new MemoryStream(), spreadsheetDocument.DocumentType);
            WorkbookPart tempWorkbookPart = tempSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
            WorksheetPart tempWorksheetPart = tempWorkbookPart.AddPart<WorksheetPart>(sourceSheetPart);

            WorksheetPart clonedSheet = workbookPart.AddPart<WorksheetPart>(tempWorksheetPart);

            Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
            Sheet copiedSheet = new Sheet
            {
                Name = clonedSheetName,
                Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(clonedSheet),
                SheetId = (uint) sheets.ChildElements.Count + 1
            };

            sheets.Append(copiedSheet);
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
    }
```

The ouput is as expected but the embedded files are copied as "Picture" rather than "Object". I unzipped .xlsx file and all looks legit ie. similar to the sheet I copied. Yet still the file cannot be opened on the copied sheet. All images, strings are displayed in correct way.

**2. Embedding the object**

What I understand I need to do is:

1. Convert object into oleObject - this will be separate fun.
2. Add DrawingsPart - It looks like it's read-only and I can only add ImagePart.
3. Embed Object
4. Connect both drawing and embedded object part toghether and allocate to some range in spreadsheet.

   ```
       static void EmbedFileXlsx(string path, string embeddedFilePath, string placeholderImagePath)
   {
       using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(path, true))
       {
           WorksheetPart sourceSheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadsheetDocument, "Test");

           var imagePart = sourceSheetPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Emf, "rId1");
           imagePart.FeedData(File.Open(placeholderImagePath, FileMode.Open));

           var embeddedObject =
               sourceSheetPart.AddEmbeddedObjectPart(@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject");
           embeddedObject.FeedData(File.Open(embeddedFilePath, FileMode.Open));

           spreadsheetDocument.Save();
       }
   }
   ```

This code just adds embedded objects into the file but does not create any type of relationship between them. This means that file is not visible on the spreadsheet.

I tried copying sheets using ClosedXML as well but unfortunately this is not supported nor the embedding.

I also managed to understand how I can copy sheet into new document with all embedded objects using .xml files inside spreadsheet but I do not think this would be much productive and I would like to achieve this using all the methods inside OpenXML. It looks everything is there but something is amiss.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in this, but could this help you on your way?

```
spreadsheetDocument.CreateRelationshipToPart(SOME ID);
```